# How can I change serialized data using the best_in_place gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, best-in-place

I have a model with serialized data and I want to edit this data using the `best_in_place` gem. This isn't possible by default when using the best_in_place gem. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by extending `method_missing` and `respond_to_missing?` to forward the requests to the serialized data. Lets say you have your serialized `Hash` in `data`. In the class that's containing the serialized data you can for example use this code:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *arguments, &block) # forewards the arguments to the correct methods
  if method_name.to_s =~ /data_(.+)\=/
    key = method_name.to_s.match(/data_(.+)=/)[1]
    self.send('data_setter=', key, arguments.first)
  elsif method_name.to_s =~ /data_(.+)/
    key = method_name.to_s.match(/data_(.+)/)[1]
    self.send('data_getter', column_number)
  else
    super
  end
end

def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false) # prevents giving UndefinedMethod error
  method_name.to_s.start_with?('data_') || super
end

def data_getter(key)
  self.data[key.to_i] if self.data.kind_of?(Array)
  self.data[key.to_sym] if self.data.kind_of?(Hash)
end

def data_setter(key, value)
  self.data[key.to_i] = value if self.data.kind_of?(Array)
  self.data[key.to_sym] = value if self.data.kind_of?(Hash)
  value # the method returns value because best_in_place sets the returned value as text
end
```

Now you can access the object.data[:name] using the getter object.data_name and set value using the setter object.data_name="test". But to get this working using `best_in_place` you need to dynamicly add it to the `attr_accessible` list. To do this you need to change the behavior of the `mass_assignment_authorizer` and make the object respond to `accessable_methods` with an array of method names that should be allowed to be edited like this:

```
def accessable_methods # returns a list of all the methods that are responded dynamicly
  self.data.keys.map{|x| "data_#{x.to_s}".to_sym }
end

private
  def mass_assignment_authorizer(user) # adds the list to the accessible list.
    super + self.accessable_methods
  end
```

So in the View you can now call

```
  best_in_place @object, :data_name
```

To edit the serialized data of @object.data[:name]

// You can also do this for an array using the element index instead of the attribute name:

```
<% @object.data.count.times do |index| %>
  <%= best_in_place @object, "data_#{index}".to_sym %>
<% end %>
```

You dont need to change the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you for this. What about non-associated Array/Hash? Would it be possible to have something similar for arrays without keys? Here's my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415176/how-to-edit-a-serialized-array-with-unknown-keys

Thanks!

Comment: See edit added an extnsion on how to use this for arrays

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! However it doesn't work, I am getting an Unpermitted_parameters: data_0 in the console when trying to update the value. I guess it has something to do with the strong parameters. In the meantime I'm switching back to the old way (using inputs).

Comment: Phenomenal answer, two quick things to note. I had to change `column_number` to `key` and `def data_setter(key, value)` to `def data_setter=(key, value)` for everything to work!