# render form with json data using postgre hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, postgresql-9.2, form-for, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a Attributes column in one of my model,

and the `Attributes column` is hstore type, it stores JSON format string,

I want my user to edit it in normal form type,

I wish it could span to 4 input-fields automatically,

`name`

`range`

`security`

`default_value`

is there any gem to achieve it ?

[image]

### UPDATE

I followed  @zwippie solution, and show it in the form correctly,

But it can not be updated,

When I tried to updated it,

But I should add those fields into strong parameters,

is there any dynamic way, to achieve this.

To expand all the columns in the hstro rather than hard code `store_accessor :cgi_attributes, :name, :range, :security, :default_value`,
and also append it into white list

```
= f.text_area column, class: 'input-xxlarge'
```

But it

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 can do this out of the box. Add this to your model:

```
store_accessor :attributes, :name, :range, :security, :default_value
```

Now you can use the hstore attributes as normal Active Record attributes:

```
item = Item.find(2)
item.update(security: '5/6')
```

Or in a form:

```
<%= f.text_field :default_value %>
```

Comment: I followed you solution , but there still some problems , I updated my post, thank you for your support :)

Comment: @newBike, I know this is old, but in case someone else sees this, make sure to update your strong parameters to accept the store_accessors.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think theres a gem to achive it but its still possible using metaprogamming.

Using metaprogramming you can create methods dynamicly based on the data of an object. I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286988/1001324) for serialized data which is very likely to your situation.

The thing you need to extend is the view but thats not such a problem you can simpley call a methed that returns all keys of the serialized data and then loop through them and generate inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [PostgreSQL hstore](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/using-postgresql-hstore-in-a-rails-application-on-engine-yard-cloud)  might be useful if your are using a postgresql database in your application.