# How to edit a serialized array with known keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415176/how-to-edit-a-serialized-array-with-unknown-keys) on how to edit serialized columns in Rails, where the keys are unknown.

In my case, I want to be able to edit an array of hashes where the keys are actually known, in the serialized attribute.

An example:

```
class Person
     serialize :addresses
end
```

Where in Addresses would be an array of hashes:

```
{
  line_1: "1 First Street",
  line_2: "Apt 202",
  city: "Tampa",
  state: "FL",
  zip: "12313"
}
```

And since I would know the index of this hash within the array with the each_with_index on a show view, I want to be able to edit the information in an edit or a new form view.

Comment: On the controller of your update, you could easily to something like `person.addresses[index][:city] = "Miami"` if you need to change some attributes. You also need to `person.save` to persist the change.

Comment: so in the views itself, do I use fields_for, or do I do it manually by name="person[addresses[I]][city]" where person is the model, I is the index?  Is that the correct syntax?  then in the controller keep it to params.require(:person).permit(addresses: [])?

Comment: Just a suggestion (certainly not an answer) but why not just just persist this data in a RDBMS instead? It would be a lot easier to manage the Addresses if this was a relationship rather than a serialized column.

Comment: @PatrickVellia `fields_for` should work. However, you might need to adapt a little bit  your strong parameter since `params.require(:person).permit(addresses: [])` would allow any parameters in your addresses. Probably something like (not sure of the syntax) : `params.require(:person).permit(addresses: [:line_1, :line_2, :city, :state, :zip])`. The "clean" and easier solution would be what @engineersmnky suggested and store it in db.